# Android Bitmap createScaledBitmap returning null as result

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I 'm trying to create a Bitmap from a path but it's always returning null, the bitmapOrg is always null. I've verified the path and it's correct, I don't know where the problem is coming from. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
    opts.inSampleSize = 2;
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.path, opts), 97, 97, true);
```

Also, can anybody tell me what's the best method to use to compress a Bitmap without resizing it please ? I've tried this :

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();

    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
```

Thanks !

Comment: it's an attribute, it contains the path to the selected image, in a first time the image is shown then I want to compress it

Comment: What is its value? At least include your full code here.